# Extract string from string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to extract the following

```
test-09112015-143033
```

from my string:

```
"HEAD,tag: refs/tags/test-09112015-143033,refs/remotes/origin/test"
```

The following works when there is nothing after.

```
function getSecondPart(str) {
    return str.split('/tags/')[1];
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m0yat5rg/)**

How can I solve this when there is something after like (or something else of course)

```
,refs/remotes/origin/test
```

Comment: is there a reason you couldn't just call .split again on the comma?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? I assume you do not want the literal string `test-09112015-143033`, because you already have it. Can the digits vary? Is the prefix `text` fixed? Can the length of the parts vary? What is the substring embedded in? Is there any regularity to it?

Comment: I just want it to stop at the comma actually

Comment: try `str.split('/tags/')[1].split(',')[0];`

Comment: Thanks that works, you can make an answer if u want me to accept it

Comment: Will there always be a `refs/tags/...` in that string? What should happen if not? I encourage you to read [ask] to learn how to write better questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure that your string will always between `/tags/` and `,` you can use :

```js
function getSecondPart(str) {
    return str.match("/tags/([^,]+),")[1];
}

// use the function:
console.log(getSecondPart("HEAD,tag: refs/tags/test-09112015-143033,refs/remotes/origin/test"));
```

hope this helps.

Comment: It may be safer (and more performant) to use `[^,]+` instead of matching everything eagerly.